# Any links or HTML form items like button inside the Bootstrap 4 modal is unusable

Tags: event-handling, bootstrap-modal, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have cart icon, which when clicked loads the cart of the user in a Modal. However, any link or HTML form items like input or buttons that are within this modal are unusable. It can never be brought to focus nor clicked. I tried playing with CSS property `z-index` with no success.

[Check site here.](http://test-frenli-pon.pantheonsite.io/?#)

Add any product to cart and then click bag/cart icon on the top right to see the issue.

Comment: They are unusable because `modal-dialog` has a CSS clause `pointer-events: none;`, it works when removed.
Try wrapping the body of your modal in a `modal-content` (which provide a `pointer-events: auto;` clause) instead of `content` or just add `pointer-events: auto;` to `content`

By the way, your modal is not closable

Comment: @BadMiscuit This solved my issue. Thanks. If you could have posted this as an answer, I could have accepted it.

Answer (score -1):

Changing the `pointer-events` value in CSS solved the issue. wrapping the content part in an element with class `modal-content` is also fixing the issue as suggested in comments.